# How can you contact the winner on an Apple Game Centre leaderboard?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm about to launch an iOS game, with game centre support. At the end of each month I would like to contact the winner and offer them a prize. Is it possible to do this though the iTunes connect, or some other system?

I can't find much within the Apple developer doc's and the alternatives all seem a bit long winded.

Comment: I don't believe you can, but it is probably a bad idea anyway. The Game Center leader board are routinely spammed with bogus scores anyway

Comment: Whilst researching this I have come across a lot of similar comments and frustrations. I always wondered why I could never get near the highest scores! As a result, thinking twice about doing this, if it's even possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. The Apple guidelines strongly suggest that they want to keep the personal details of the user away from the developers. Also, it is not a good practice to incentivise the winners outside the app!

Plus as Paulw11 put it, the Game Centre leaderboards are usually spammed, and you finding a player with a genuine high score is difficult.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when looking through the App Store Review Guidelines, section 20 Contests, sweepstakes, lotteries, raffles, and gambling it looks a bit different. The these two sections would suggest that its possible to offer a prize:  - 20.1 Sweepstakes and contests must be sponsored by the developer/company of the App  - 20.2 Official rules for sweepstakes and contests must be presented in the App and make it clear that Apple is not a sponsor or involved in the activity in any manner. But how do you get the prize to the winner?

Comment: I think that what they mean by this is that we can have a contest outside the app, separately and not by calling the leaderboard players particularly.

Comment: Think I will have to do it another way, I suspected as much when I started this, but the Review guidelines gave me false hope.